# Find record with LIKE on partial attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my app I have invoice numbers like this:

```
2014.DEV.0001
2014.DEV.0002
2014.TSZ.0003
```

The three character code is a company code. When a new invoice number needs to be assigned it should look for the last used invoice number for that specific company code and add one to it.

I know the company code, I use a `LIKE` to search on a partial invoice number like this:

```
last = Invoice.where("invoice_nr LIKE ?", "#{DateTime.now.year}.#{company_short}.").last
```

This results in this SQL query:

```
SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."account_id" = 1 AND (invoice_nr LIKE '2014.TSZ.') ORDER BY "invoices"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

But unfortunately it doesn't return any results. Any idea to improve this, as searching with `LIKE` doesn't seem to be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping string with `%` and use `lower` to convert the query string and result into downcase to avoid any wrong results due to `case`, try this

```
last = Invoice.where("lower(invoice_nr) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{DateTime.now.year}.#{company_short}.%").last
```

Comment: Let me explain it in brief, let's say data in the database is saved as "abCD" and we are querying it with "ABCD" then it won't fetch the desired result. When we use lower on both sides, query string "ABCD" will be converted to "abcd" and also "abCD" which is in the database will be fetched and converted to downcase "abcd" then after both will be compared. So in the later case we will get correct data.

Comment: ohhk ..got it i saw only one lower earlier that why gets confuse thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

You want % for partial match

```
last = Invoice.where("invoice_nr LIKE ?", "%#{DateTime.now.year}.#{company_short}.%").last
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to match only the left part you need to add one `%` at the right part of your string

```
Invoice.where("invoice_nr LIKE ?", "#{DateTime.now.year}.#{company_short}.%").last
```